# How to set Tab View Indicator background color in Android

Tags: android

How to Change color on click tab Host. i can change image but color are not change.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TabHost tabHost=(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
        tabHost.setup();

        TabSpec spec1=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 1");
        spec1.setContent(R.id.tab1);`enter code here`
        spec1.setIndicator("Tab 1", getResources().getDrawable(setBackgroundColor(Color.RED));

        TabSpec spec2=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 2");
        spec2.setIndicator("Tab 2", getResources().getDrawable(setBackgroundColor(Color.GREAN));
        spec2.setContent(R.id.tab2);

        TabSpec spec3=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 3");
        spec3.setIndicator("Tab 3", getResources().getDrawable(setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK));
        spec3.setContent(R.id.tab3);

        tabHost.addTab(spec1);
        tabHost.addTab(spec2);
        tabHost.addTab(spec3);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TabHost tabHost=(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
        tabHost.setup();

        TabSpec spec1=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 1");
        spec1.setContent(R.id.tab1);`enter code here`
        spec1.setIndicator("Tab 1", getResources().getDrawable(setBackgroundColor(view.Color.RED));

        TabSpec spec2=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 2");
        spec2.setIndicator("Tab 2", getResources().getDrawable(setBackgroundColor(view.Color.GREAN));
        spec2.setContent(R.id.tab2);

        TabSpec spec3=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 3");
        spec3.setIndicator("Tab 3", getResources().getDrawable(setBackgroundColor(view.Color.BLACK));
        spec3.setContent(R.id.tab3);

        tabHost.addTab(spec1);
        tabHost.addTab(spec2);
        tabHost.addTab(spec3);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this function just pass your tabHost in it

```
public static void setTabColor(TabHost tabhost) {
        for(int i=0;i<tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
        {
            tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(R.color.white); //unselected
        }
        tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabhost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundResource(R.color.tab_selected); // selected
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

//set background colors for tabs

```
   for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(i).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gradient));

       }
```

Answer (score -3):

For that your should use the event onTabChangedlistener and inside put any of the loops that you want as in the picked answer.

```java
tabhost.setOnTabChangedListener(new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String s) {
            setTabColor(tabhost); 
        }
    });
```

You can read at this article, this will help you but it's in spanish.

http://www.johnarij.ml/2017/04/19/cambio-de-color-de-tab-en-tabhost-android/

Comment: The question is 5 years old and has an accepted answer. Linking to a non-English general article about the subject adds little value.