# How to change the color of tab indicator

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabhost, android-tabs

I am using tabHost in my application and the requirement is that when any tab is selected the color of tab indicator should change ,I referred this example [How to set Tab View Indicator background color in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373443/how-to-set-tab-view-indicator-background-color-in-android) but i didn't understood 
Here is my code:

```
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost

            TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Reusable TabSpec for each tab
            Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

            // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
            intent = new Intent().setClass(this, HomePage.class);
            // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
            spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tabOne");  
            spec.setContent(intent);  
            spec.setIndicator("Home");  
            tabHost.addTab(spec);
            // Squash the tab a little bit horizontally
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().height = 40;
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().width = 50;

            // Bump the text size upll.getChildAt(0);

            // Do the same for the other tabs
            intent = new Intent().setClass(this, MoteIt.class);
            spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tabTwo");  
            spec.setContent(intent);  
            spec.setIndicator("moteit");

            tabHost.addTab(spec);
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).getLayoutParams().height = 40;


            intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Lifeline.class);
            spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tabThree");  
            spec.setContent(intent);  
            spec.setIndicator("lifeline");
            tabHost.addTab(spec);
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).getLayoutParams().height = 40;


            intent = new Intent().setClass(this, CircleOfTrust.class);
            spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tabfour");  
            spec.setContent(intent);  
            spec.setIndicator("Cot");
            tabHost.addTab(spec);
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).getLayoutParams().height = 40;

            intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Search.class);
            spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tabFive");  
            spec.setContent(intent);  
            spec.setIndicator("Search");
            tabHost.addTab(spec);
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(4).getLayoutParams().height = 40;
            tabHost.getTabWidget().setStripEnabled(true);
            tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This solution works for me and also its working for 2.1+ android, its create custom tab layout

Code:

```
private TabHost mTabHost;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    setupTabHost();
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(R.drawable.fake_divider);

    setupTab(new TextView(this), "123", R.id.tab1);
    setupTab(new TextView(this), "abc", R.id.tab2);
    setupTab(new TextView(this), "fav", R.id.tab3);

    mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
}

private void setupTabHost() {
    mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup();
}

private void setupTab(final View view, final String tag, final int res) {
    View tabview = createTabView(mTabHost.getContext(), tag);
    TabSpec setContent = mTabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tabview).setContent(res);
    mTabHost.addTab(setContent);
}

private static View createTabView(final Context context, final String text) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tabwidget_bg, null);
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabsText);
    tv.setText(text);
    return view;
}
```

in main.xml:

```
<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/tab_divider" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:measureAllChildren="true" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:baselineAligned="true"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
        ... etc
```

custom layout tabwidget_bg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tabsLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/tab_bg_selector"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tabsText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now you can customize your custom tab layot as u can, and color of your active tab n tab_bg_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Active tab -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bg_selected" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <!-- Inactive tab -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bg_unselected" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false"/>
    <!-- Pressed tab -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bg_active" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <!-- Selected tab (using d-pad) -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bg_selected" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true"/>

</selector>
```

Comment: Small note. The first parameter of setupTab() is not used. Anyway, i'm trying your solution now. 10x

Comment: But no need for declaring the method  `createTabView ` as a `static` unless you are going to use it from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    PagerTabStrip tabStrip = (PagerTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.pager_title_strip);
    tabStrip.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(240, 240, 240));
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you please explain that What is my pager tab strip here?

Comment: Can you please send me the Xml code for 'R.id.pager_title_strip' because i am getting null pointer exception, I am using a view for this.

Answer (score -1):

You can set color in layout xml.

```
android:background = "@color/....";
```

Comment: where do I add this Here is my XML:
<TabHost android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>

Comment: into your layout whic you want

Comment: actually this changes the color of the layout but i want to change the underline color i.e. tab indicator.
If it works for you then please give me an example because i am new in this field